# In RadAsyncUpload when target folder is not set then how to delete temp file in .net

Tags: .net, telerik

I have created a file uploader RadAsyncUpload. Post uploading a file it is getting save in temp (~/App_Data\RadUploadTemp) folder. I have a upload button which save that file from temp folder to database. I need to delete the file from temp folder after saving into database. Is there any method in telerik availble, as i read if we do not set target folder the files will be deleted after 40 min but its not happening in my case. The name of file is created dynamically so also it is difficult to delete using pure file system through programming.
I am using .net

Comment: Couldn't you just delete everything in the temp folder after successfully saving to the database.

Comment: In temp folder file name is appended with some GUID so do not have the complete name for file to be deleted.

Comment: You don't need the name of the file to delete it.  Get all files in the temp directory and loop through them, deleting each one.